# How can I play content from a media server?

Tags: xbox-360

I have my Xbox 360 playing content from my ubuntu 10.04 PC using minidlna application.

What software could I install on my laptop to play the same content from my PC?

Totem does not appear to have a browse option.

Comment: See also [How can I Push/Stream media to my Ubuntu box from a DNLA device](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45949/how-can-i-push-stream-media-to-my-ubuntu-box-from-a-dnla-device) for something similar, but trying to control it from the media server (e.g. a phone) and use the Ubuntu box as the equivalent of a DNLP enabled TV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the package totem-plugins-extra. You can find it in the Software Centre or just use:

```
sudo apt-get install totem-plugins-extra
```

from the command line.

Now open Totem, go to Edit -> Plugin, check that the coherence plugin is installed.

In the dropbox of the sidebar select **Coherence DLNA/UPnP Client**. You should be able to browse your server from there.

You can find more info in the totem [plug-ins webpage.](http://library.gnome.org/users/totem/stable/totem-plugins.html.en)