# How can I Push/Stream media to my Ubuntu box from a DNLA device

Tags: software-recommendation, mediaserver, upnp

I would like to use my Ubuntu box as the equivalent of a DNLP enabled TV. 
I would like to be able to from my phone, send video to the computer's monitor.
so basically the opposite of using vlc to play a video from a network source; I'm looking to have the network source push the video to the computer. 
are there any programs for this?

Comment: Good question.  See [How can I play content from a media server? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4615/how-can-i-play-content-from-a-media-server) for the case where you want to control it from the Ubuntu end (pull it to the player client rather than pushing from the server).

Answer (score 1):

If you install the `totem-plugins-extra` package, then the standard movie player can be used to browse and play content stored on DLNA media servers on your network.  Just follow these steps:

1. Install the `totem-plugins-extra` package.
2. Start the movie player and choose `Plugins...` from the `Edit` menu.
3. Check the box next to `Coherence DLNA/UPnP Client` and close the plugins window.
4. Pick the `Coherence DLNA/UPnP Client` panel on the side bar.  If the side bar is not displayed, press <kbd>F9</kbd> to open it.

You should now be able to browse through the media advertised by the media servers on the local network.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. VLC does this fine for me, I was wondering if the opposite was possible. have the media source push the video to the computer as opposed to the computer pulling the video from the source.

Comment: Okay.  Rygel has a DLNA media renderer interface in its `rygel-playbin` package, but it isn't properly integrated with the movie player: you just get a window with no controls pop up on screen when a control point asks it to start playing a media file.  I believe the aim is to get this stuff merged in to the movie player, but that hasn't happened yet.